# What is a wide column in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, terminology

I've seen the following terms used:

- `wide field` – e.g. "the TOAST mechanism first attempts to compress any wide field values"
- `wide column` – e.g. "If you have many wide columns" or "even complete toasting doesn't allow a row with more than about 450 wide columns".

But I haven't seen them defined.

I understand Posgres has a page/block size limit (typically of 8192 bytes) and that it will rely on TOAST when the data doesn't fit within the limit. But, as I understand it, this is based *on the size of the row*, not on the size of any one column. So I understand how one could say a row to be wide… but a particular column? (But maybe I'm taking this too literally.)

In this context, **what's the threshold for considering a column to be `wide`?**

Comment: [Docs are here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html)

Comment: I read that page before posting.

Comment: Did this not answer your question? "The TOAST management code is triggered only when a row value to be stored in a table is wider than TOAST_TUPLE_THRESHOLD bytes (normally 2 kB). The TOAST code will compress and/or move field values out-of-line until the row value is shorter than TOAST_TUPLE_TARGET bytes (also normally 2 kB, adjustable) or no more gains can be had."  If you need more specificity than that, you probably need to consult the source code.

Comment: So what's a `wide column` in all that? A column that has _at least one row_ over TOAST_TUPLE_THRESHOLD in size? It's the docs referring to *rows* all the time but the term referring to a *column* that's confusing me.